# MySQL Relational Select Issue

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I'm trying to select all jobs that a user has been added to, but exclude jobs that they have declined. I've been looking into NOT EXISTS, but I haven't been able to exclude declined jobs with that.

Table: declined

```
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|      id |  job_id | user_id | declined |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
|      15 |     223 |      25 |        1 |
|     100 |     156 |      50 |        1 |
|     125 |     651 |      60 |        1 |
+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Current query. Selects all jobs they've been added to, as well as jobs they have declined.

```
SELECT
    job.*, applicants.*, declined.*
FROM job
    JOIN applicants ON job.job_id = applicants.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN declined ON job.job_id = declined.job_id
WHERE applicants.user_id = '" .  $userId . "' AND applicants.recruited = 1
```

Failed attempt. This obviously does not select any records.

```
SELECT
    job.*, applicants.*, declined.*
FROM job
    JOIN applicants ON job.job_id = applicants.job_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN declined ON job.job_id = declined.job_id
WHERE applicants.user_id = '" .  $userId . "' AND applicants.recruited = 1 AND declined.declined = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NOT IN` to exclude the declined jobs:

```
SELECT
    job.*, applicants.*
FROM job
    JOIN applicants ON job.job_id = applicants.job_id
WHERE applicants.user_id = '" .  $userId . "' AND applicants.recruited = 1
AND job.job_id not in (
  SELECT DISTINCT job_id from declined where user_id = '" .  $userId . "' and declined = 1
)
```

One more thing - not sure what language you're using, but you shouldn't set $userId like that, use a parameterized query, it's much safer than building the query like that.

Comment: Thank you for this. Yes, going to move over to parameterized PDO at some point in the near future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT
    job.*, applicants.*
FROM job, applicants
WHERE job.job_id = applicants.job_id
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM declined WHERE job.job_id = declined.job_id AND declined.user_id = applicants.user_id AND declined.declined = 1)
AND applicants.user_id = '" .  $userId . "' 
AND applicants.recruited = 1
```